# Creating a component similar to Outlooks email/contact lookup

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, extjs4

I want to create a contact lookup similar to outlook. I am planning to use the extjs combobox for this functionality. The demo present on the site does allow me to type the string and it automatically matches with values present in store and displays it to me.

Also it has a multi select option using which i can select multiple values from drop down.

But i need this scenario when i type the required string i.e.

Suppose i have 4 values in combo box (Red,Yello,Green,White). Now when i type Green it shows me the drop down containing Green and i can select it using enter or mouse click. Now if after selecting first value i type colon or comma and again start searching i am unable to get the results.

Can this be possible using Extjs or is there any other way of implementing.

I am using Jsp, Html and Javascript along with ExtJs.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a user built extension to combobox called [BoxSelect](http://kveeiv.github.com/extjs-boxselect/examples/boxselect.html) . It has many more config options and I believe your exact use case.